# LibGDX: Downloading and Loading Model from a Web Address for Android

Tags: android, libgdx

I have a g3db model file saved on my server (eg. http://website.com/model.g3db). I want to load that model into my android application.

I have tried asyncTask in my launcher class to first download the file locally and then use this downloaded file to load the model. But it didn't work.

**AndroidLauncher.java**

```
public class AndroidLauncher extends AndroidApplication {

public final static String FILENAME = "model";
public static final int DIALOG_DOWNLOAD_PROGRESS = 0;
private ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;

private LinearLayout modelView;

private Viewer viewer; // Viewer Class

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.viewer);

    modelView = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.view);

    startDownload();
}

private void startDownload() {
    String url = "http://website.com/model.g3db";
    new DownloadFileAsync().execute(url);
}

@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    switch (id) {
        case DIALOG_DOWNLOAD_PROGRESS:
            mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
            mProgressDialog.setMessage("Downloading file..");
            mProgressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
            mProgressDialog.setCancelable(false);
            mProgressDialog.show();
            return mProgressDialog;
        default:
            return null;
    }
}

class DownloadFileAsync extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        file = new File(getFilesDir(), FILENAME);
        showDialog(DIALOG_DOWNLOAD_PROGRESS);
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... aurl) {
        int count;
        try {
            URL url = new URL(aurl[0]);
            URLConnection conexion = url.openConnection();
            conexion.connect();

            int lenghtOfFile = conexion.getContentLength();
            Log.d("ANDRO_ASYNC", "Lenght of file: " + lenghtOfFile);

            InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream());
            OutputStream output = openFileOutput(FILENAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

            byte data[] = new byte[1024];

            long total = 0;

            while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
                total += count;
                publishProgress(""+(int)((total*100)/lenghtOfFile));
                output.write(data, 0, count);
            }

            output.flush();
            output.close();
            input.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(AndroidLauncher.this, "File Writing Problem", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        return null;

    }
    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... progress) {
        Log.d("ANDRO_ASYNC",progress[0]);
        mProgressDialog.setProgress(Integer.parseInt(progress[0]));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String unused) {
        dismissDialog(DIALOG_DOWNLOAD_PROGRESS);

        // Now Initialize Viewer class as we have the model downloaded locally
        AndroidApplicationConfiguration config = new AndroidApplicationConfiguration();
        config.useGLSurfaceView20API18 = true;
        viewer = new Viewer();
        modelView.addView(initializeForView(viewer, config));
    }
}
```

**Viewer.java**

```
private FileHandle fileHandle;
private ModelLoader modelLoader;

@Override
public void create () {
    stage = new Stage();
    font = new BitmapFont();
    label = new Label(" ", new Label.LabelStyle(font, Color.WHITE));

    stage.addActor(label);
    stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

    modelBatch = new ModelBatch();
    environment = new Environment();
    environment.set(new ColorAttribute(ColorAttribute.AmbientLight, 0.4f, 0.4f, 0.4f, 1f));
    environment.add(new DirectionalLight().set(0.8f, 0.8f, 0.8f, -1f, -0.8f, -0.2f));

    cam = new PerspectiveCamera(67, Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
    cam.position.set(10,21,0);
    cam.lookAt(0,0,0);
    cam.up.set(Vector3.Y);
    cam.near = 5;
    cam.far = 70;
    cam.update();

    camController = new CameraInputController(cam);
    Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(new InputMultiplexer(this, camController));

    // Locally Stored Model File -----
    handle = Gdx.files.local("model.g3db");

    UBJsonReader jsonReader = new UBJsonReader();
    modelLoader = new G3dModelLoader(jsonReader);

    loading = true;
}

private void doneLoading () {
    Model model = modelLoader.loadModel(fileHandle);

    for (int i = 0; i < model.nodes.size; i++) {
        String id = model.nodes.get(i).id;
        GameObject instance = new GameObject(model, id, true);
        instances.add(instance);
    }
    loading = false;
}
```

But i got error when i run the app

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {in.SpaceFix.SpaceFix.android/in.SpaceFix.SpaceFix.android.AndroidLauncher}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidInput.onResume()' on a null object reference
              at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3137)
              at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3168)
              at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2522)
              at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:162)
              at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1412)
              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:189)
              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5530)
              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:950)
              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:745)
       Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidInput.onResume()' on a null object reference
              at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidApplication.onResume(AndroidApplication.java:293)
              at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1246)
              at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:6052)
              at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3122)
              at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3168)
              at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2522)
              at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:162)
              at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1412)
              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:189)
              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5530)
              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:950)
              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:745)
```

Kindly Help !

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're postponing to create your `ApplicationListener`, that wont work. `AndroidApplication` expects to have a valid `ApplicationListener`. Make it look like [this](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Starter-classes-%26-configuration#android):

```
@Override
protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    AndroidApplicationConfiguration config = new AndroidApplicationConfiguration();
    config.useGLSurfaceView20API18 = true;
    viewer = new Viewer();
    modelView.addView(initializeForView(viewer, config));
}
```

Also, you should [use an interface to use platform specific code](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Interfacing-with-platform-specific-code). However if you really want to take the road you took, then you could inform your viewer that you're done downloading:

```
viewer.downloadComplete();
```

And in your `Viewer` class you can place the specific code that needs to be executed after the download in that method:

```
public void downloadComplete()
{
    handle = Gdx.files.local("model.g3db");
    UBJsonReader jsonReader = new UBJsonReader();
    modelLoader = new G3dModelLoader(jsonReader);
    Model model = modelLoader.loadModel(fileHandle);
    for (int i = 0; i < model.nodes.size; i++) {
        String id = model.nodes.get(i).id;
        GameObject instance = new GameObject(model, id, true);
        instances.add(instance);
    }
}
```

Btw, it looks like you took the code of [my tutorial](http://xoppa.github.io/blog/loading-models-using-libgdx/) using `AssetManager` and modified it in that way that it doesn't make sense. You should either use `AssetManager` or dont need that `loading` and `doneLoading()` mechanism.

That said, it should be noted that downloading a file isn't a platform specific functionality and thus can be done from within your `ApplicationListener`. Have a look at the [HttpRequest](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/Net.HttpRequest.html) class for more information. This would look something like this:

```
Model model;
@Override
public void create () {
    stage = new Stage();
    font = new BitmapFont();
    label = new Label(" ", new Label.LabelStyle(font, Color.WHITE));

    stage.addActor(label);
    stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

    modelBatch = new ModelBatch();
    environment = new Environment();
    environment.set(new ColorAttribute(ColorAttribute.AmbientLight, 0.4f, 0.4f, 0.4f, 1f));
    environment.add(new DirectionalLight().set(0.8f, 0.8f, 0.8f, -1f, -0.8f, -0.2f));

    cam = new PerspectiveCamera(67, Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
    cam.position.set(10,21,0);
    cam.lookAt(0,0,0);
    cam.up.set(Vector3.Y);
    cam.near = 5;
    cam.far = 70;
    cam.update();

    camController = new CameraInputController(cam);
    Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(new InputMultiplexer(this, camController));

    Net.HttpRequest request = new Net.HttpRequest(Net.HttpMethods.GET);
    request.setUrl("http://website.com/model.g3db");
    Gdx.net.sendHttpRequest(request, new HttpResponseListener() {
        @Override
        public void handleHttpResponse (HttpResponse httpResponse) {
            final FileHandle tmpFile = FileHandle.tempFile("model");
            tmpFile.write(httpResponse.getResultAsStream(), false);
            Gdx.app.postRunnable(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run () {
                    model = new G3dModelLoader(new UBJsonReader()).loadModel(tmpFile);
                    for (int i = 0; i < model.nodes.size; i++) {
                        String id = model.nodes.get(i).id;
                        GameObject instance = new GameObject(model, id, true);
                        instances.add(instance);
                    }
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public void failed (Throwable t) {
            Gdx.app.error("Test", "something went wrong", t);
        }

        @Override
        public void cancelled () {
            Gdx.app.log("Test", "cancelled");
        }
    });
}
```

Although not related to your question, please keep in mind that `Model` need to be disposed. You are creating a new `Model` in your `doneLoading()` method, but never disposes it. You might want to reconsider your approach on that since it will cause leaking resources.

Comment: I tried the code and it successfully download the model.g3db file BUT it never get rendered. It seems that `model = new G3dModelLoader(new UBJsonReader()).loadModel(tmpFile);` in your code never completes execution (or it is taking too much time to load model).

Comment: My model file size is only 74KB, so size should not be a problem while loading.

Comment: It works fine for me. Check you log and debugger to see what's going on.